# Why is jQuery UI toggle not working in my theme?

Tags: javascript

I've tried setting up a jQuery toggle menu without much success. I followed the exact instructions and code from [this tutorial](http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/drupal-theming-jquery-basics-inc-drupal-behaviors), but even this simple script is not working.

Regular JS (like an alert) seems to work fine. I have [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) installed and it seems the views admin uses extensive jQuery and works fine. Is there something I have to do to enable jQuery on my theme?

Comment: Did you clear cache?, e.g Admin > Config > Performance

Comment: Thanks David, yes I cleared it several times, and manually ran CRON then cleared it again, still no joy. I am running a custom theme, do I need to load/install jQuery on it or is it supposed to be available globally?

Comment: jQuery is added by Drupal core and is available globally. Check your script.js has been added to the html source.

Comment: Ah, glad it's sorted! re: comment upvoting, there's a little triangle that shows on comment hover.  All the best, DT

Comment: @David,  I deleted my previous comment by mistake. Your answer worked, I included the following preprocess in my module: `code`  function myTheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/scripts/myTheme.js','file');
 }    ps not sure why but hover upvote doens't come on for me perhaps I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @DavidThomas would you like to move your comment to answer I can accept it and close the question (unless there's some other way I can do that from a comment?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is added by Drupal core and is available globally.

Clear cache at Admin > Config > Performance

Check your script.js has been added to the html source.